# Creating Generic groups for SSRS Report Access

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Is there a way to provide generic permissions for users to run reports stored in the Report Manager? I can see how to provide access on an individual user basis via Manage -> Security -> New Role Assignment, by adding the User's Windows login name and assigning them to the Browser role for the report. (Report Manager already knows the domain name).

However, we don't want to be continually having to manage this for each new user. I want anyone under that domain name to have access without needing to configure it. I had hoped that just adding the domain name as a 'user' to the Browser role for that report would do it, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any domain group that has been set up, not just individual users, or you can simply add all domain users, i.e. `MYDOMAIN\Domain Users` to the **Browser** role, which seems to be what you're after.

However, I would recommend creating a generic user group like `MYDOMAIN\SSRSReportUsers` or something like that and adding this group to the browser role instead of `MYDOMAIN\Domain Users`, as adding *all* users to the Report Server seems like it doesn't give you many options to manage this in any sort of granular way.

Comment: Many thanks Ian, MYDOMAIN\Domain Users is exactly what I wanted. We can control granular access to the reports using roles on the front end from which the reports are accessed.For clarification however, I did try and set up a generic user group, but couldn't see how

Comment: Oops - unfamiliar with the editor here, I'll try again.

Prior to using your solution I did set up a generic user group in Report Manager and did the same in Windows. However this solution required adding each user individually to the Windows user group which is the same situation I was trying to avoid in Report Manager!

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update! Sounds like you've found the right solution for your issue, which is the main thing - I suppose the advice at the end of the answer is pretty generic, more for someone chancing on this in the future more than anything, but you've obviously considered this no problem.

Comment: I am facing the same situation. I want to create a MYDOMAIN\SSRSReportUsers but how do I create that group. I can't find the documentation for that. Thanks!